# Which planet in the solar system is it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

> It is known that the period of revolution of the earth about the sun is $365.3$ days and that the semimajor axis of the earth's orbit is $1.495 \times 10^{11}$ m. An astronomer notes that the period of a distant planet is $29.7$ earth years. What is the semimajor exis of the distant planet's orbit? Check in a reference source (encyclopedia,etc.) what planet of the solar system this might be.

This problem is from Anderson's *Introduction to Flight*, 4th edition, Exercise 8.4.

I was presented a formula $$\left( \frac{\tau_2}{\tau_1} \right)^2=\left(\frac{a_2}{a_1} \right)^2$$
where $\tau_1, \tau_2$ denote the periods of earth and the other planet, respectively, and $a_1,a_2$ denote semi major axes of earth and the other planet respectively.

When I plug in $a_1=1.495 \times 10^{11}$ m, $\tau_1=365.3$ days, and $\tau_2=29.1 \cdot 365.3$ days, I see the equation like this:
$$\left( \frac{29.1 \cdot 365.3}{365.3} \right)^2=\left(\frac{a_2}{1.495 \times 10^{11}} \right)^2$$
Solving for $a_2$, I get $a_2 = 4.44 \times 10^{12}$. I looked up for the planet with this semi-ajor axis on Wikipedia, and it turns out to be Neptune. Am I right on this?

Comment: This belongs on [astronomy.se]. Anyway the planet with ~30 year orbit is Saturn, no math necessary.

Comment: I suspect this question is more about learning to use Kepler's laws than identifying a planet.

Comment: Well, then it's still a plug-and-chug question, which is defined as off-topic for this site.

Comment: @BlackbodyBlacklight: There's a lot of overlap between Astronomy.SE and this site, this question could very well be asked on either. Since OP asked here, we ought to keep it here w/o his/her approval.

Comment: That said, Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is slightly wrong. Take a closer look at [Kepler's third law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law) One of the ratios needs to be cubed, not squared.

After fixing that, you should get a different answer.

Comment: Even my comment's formula is wrong! It's $$\left( \frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2} \right)^2=\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2} \right)^3$$ The $3$ is on the right side instead.

Comment: Applying this, I got $a_2 = 1.41 \times 10^{12}$ m, so it's Saturn! (Right?) And yes, I realize now that you can determine the planet based on period $\tau_2$ which was given. But I wanted to also determine from $a_2$ as well.

Comment: I trust your math and reference look-up skills.